# Otto eventBus no me funciona con tres fragments

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy usando la libreria `Otto` como gestor de eventos de bus pero no me funciona bien.
Pongamos Tengo tres `Fragments` digamos `FragmentA`, `FragmentB` y `FragmentC` dentro de una misma `Activity.`

1.-El `FragmentB` recibe un entero del `FragmentA`. Para ello en el `FragmentA` hace :

```
   //FRAGMENT_A
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    }
  @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView();
      BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
    }
```

y postea un valor:

```
  BusProvider.getInstance().post(5);
```

Ahora el `FragmentB` gestiona el valor recibo

```
//FRAGMENT_B 
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    }
  @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView();
      BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
    }
@Subscribe
public void getNumberB(int num) {
     // pinta el valor
}
```

Ahora el `FragmentB` debe mandar un `double` al `FragmentC`,

```
//FRAGMENT_B
private void mandarAfragmetC(double numero){
 BusProvider.getInstance().post(numero)
}
```

Ahrora el `FragmentC` lo recibe y los pinta:

```
//FRAGMENT_C 
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    }
  @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
      super.onDestroyView();
      BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
    }
@Subscribe
public void getNumberC(double num) {
     // pinta el valor
}
```

El paso del número entero de A->B si funciona bien, pero el paso del valor de  B->C no funciona, no me da ningún error, el valor nunca es recibido en el `@subscribe` del `FragmentC`

esta es mi clase de Otto

```
public class BusProvider{
    private static Bus sBus;
    public static Bus getInstance() {
        if (sBus == null)
            sBus = new Bus();
        return sBus;
    }
```

Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El metodo `Oncreate()` del `FragmentC` debe estar inicializado cuando haces

```
private void mandarAfragmetC(double numero){
 BusProvider.getInstance().post(numero)
}
```

Si no lo esta el evento del bus del `FragmentB` no encuentra ningún `@Susbcrite` cuando se genera el `.post()`